# Image effects with core graphics

Tags: iphone, cocoa, image, macos, core-graphics

I am wondering how to reproduce image effects that we can see in several Mac and iPhone applications, all of them starting from a black and white picture:
- In UiTabbar on iPhone, how, the black and white picture become a blue gradient when it is selected
- in Twitter for mac, we can see several effects (glow, bevel, ....)

Any help on this topic is welcome. :)[image]

EDIT : I am interested for these effects on MAC OS, not on iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Apple's [QuartzDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project. QuartzClipping class shows you how to work with clipping and masking. Here is what I figured out based on that project.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"at.png"];
CGImageRef alphaImage = CGImageRetain(img.CGImage);

UIImage *backgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gradientBackground.png"]; // background image for normal state
CGImageRef image = CGImageRetain(backgroundImg.CGImage);


CGFloat height = self.bounds.size.height;
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.129, 0.129, 0.129, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextClipToMask(context, CGRectMake(100.0, height - 150.0, img.size.width, img.size.height), alphaImage);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(100.0 - (backgroundImg.size.width-img.size.width)/2, 
                                       height - 150 - (backgroundImg.size.height-img.size.height)/2, 
                                       backgroundImg.size.width, 
                                       backgroundImg.size.height), image);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);



UIImage *backgroundImg2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarItemSelectedBackground.png"]; // background image for selected state
CGImageRef image2 = CGImageRetain(backgroundImg2.CGImage);

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextClipToMask(context, CGRectMake(180.0, height - 150.0, img.size.width, img.size.height), alphaImage);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(180.0 - (backgroundImg2.size.width-img.size.width)/2, 
                                       height - 150.0 - (backgroundImg2.size.height-img.size.height)/2, 
                                       backgroundImg2.size.width, 
                                       backgroundImg2.size.height), image2);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);


CGImageRelease(image);
CGImageRelease(alphaImage);
CGImageRelease(image2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately iOS is lacking the Core Image framework available in MacOSX, which is the source of all those beautiful effects. The UITabBar effects can be re-created using Core Graphics mask clipping features (see for example

```
void CGContextClipToMask (
   CGContextRef c,
   CGRect rect,
   CGImageRef mask
);
```

). This is possible because masking is based on image alpha and all tab bar buttons are alpha based (try to add in a tab bar an image which is not alpha based and you will see the final effect...).
Finally you can have a look at

```
GLImageProcessing
```

example contained in XCode documentation or [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html): this explains how to do some basic image processing using OpenGL ES 1.1 (by the way this example contains some basic texturing and rendering methods that you can reuse to integrate any OpenGL view in your UIKit based app).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is necessary to draw those since they you can obtain the same with images done with other software (photoshop, pixelmator, etc).
Why? because the content (of the button) does not change, is not resized so images are good looking and the easiest way here.

If you want to learn how to draw with Quartz, there is a lot of documents and samples in Apple dev center and/or Xcode.

This is one recent tutorial from Matt Gallagher : [Advanced drawing using AppKit](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/01/advanced-drawing-using-appkit.html)

Comment: The question was how to obtain it from code, not using photoshop. And no, there is not a lot of documentation for this kind of effect. Regarding your tutorial, it was not written by Matt Gemmell (who however produce gems of code)

Comment: That tutorial you’ve linked was written by Matt Gallagher, not Matt Gemmell.